# Disk corruption after updating arch and restarting

Tags: arch-linux, partition, ssd

I had Arch installed on a 128GB SATA SSD in BIOS/MBR mode. I did an update, (which also updated the kernel) and rebooted. Instead of rebooting properly, I got a GRUB rescue shell. I took the SSD out of that computer and plugged it into an other one.

This is what dmesg printed when I plugged it in:

```
EXT4-fs (sdc1): bad geometry: block count 29304950 exceeds size of device (29304949 blocks)
```

Running gparted with the SSD plugged in resulted in a message-box poppig up saying:

> Libparted Error Can't have a partition outside the disk!

After that message-box gparted claims that the only partition on the disk start at sector **2048** and ends at sector **234441647**, which is a bit off considering that the entire drive has **234441646** total sectors, so  there are two sectors in the partition that don't actually exist on the drive.

This is actually the second time I have this exact problem. Although I am not sure if it was an update that corrupted the drive at the first occasion. Anyways, after the first occasion I ended up reinstalling Arch, but I really don't want to do that again.

So why would an update corrupt the partitions of a drive in such a way. Could this mean that the SSD is failing? Is there a way to test if it is really failing? How should I go about fixing the partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to extract the core and apply it to your case.

1. fix part 1 should be

   ```
   fsck.ext4 -fy /dev/sdc1
   ```
2. fix part 2 should be

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/sdc1
   ```

---

Credit: Taken from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115698/fix-ext4-fs-bad-geometry-block-count-exceeds-size-of-device).